# Acceptable language in computational complexity

Tags: turing-machines

What are acceptable languages in computational complexity? Is it Turing recognizable? I was searching online and found this description. Does anyone beg to differ?

Comment: Never heard this term.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a link to the source where you saw it, and provide some context.